# Generate Dynamic table using onclick function on radio button

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp

Javascript function:

```
<script>
function pop(){
// can table get generated here??
}
</script>

<Table>
     <tr>
          <TD>
               <input type="radio" name="test" onclick= pop()>
          </TD>
          <TD>
               ${Data.getGenId().get(i)}
          </TD>
          <TD>
          ${Data.getValue1().get(i)}
     </tr>
</Table>
```

Above is my table which is getting generated dynamically.. I have a radio button in that table and as soon as I am clicking that radio button I need to make a new table just below the above table which will have `GenId` value inside that...

Is this possible to do the creation using the onclick function in javascript? or any other way?

I am a newbie and getting along with javascript and JSP any help would be very helpful.

Comment: Does the table you show have to be cloned?

Comment: no, the first column in the table above is a radio button, and second column is GenID. so when I click on radio button it should pick the GenID and show it in a new table just below the table above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This post has been edited based on discussion in the comments.**

As a newbie, your best bet here is going to be with a library like JQuery.  Using JQuery, which runs off of something called the Sizzle selector engine, you can easily insert HTML anywhere in the page.  JQuery is relatively low overhead, hosted by Google, and easy to use. JQuery is good for a lot more than this too, but this is a great use of it for a beginner.

**First,** include the following in the Head section of your HTML, before any of the script:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Second,** for convenience give your table and radio fields ID properties.  This is for later so we can work with them easily in JQuery.  We will also try and use Divs or Spans when possible with any values we need to use to avoid any problems with JQuery, because in practice it sometimes doesn't play will with tables.  I'm not sure what the .getValue1() line is doing, so I will ignore it.

```
<Table id="firstTable">
     <tr>
          <TD>
               <input type="radio" name="test" id="radioButton">
          </TD>
          <TD>
               <span id="importantColumnData">${Data.getGenId().get(i)}</span>
          </TD>
          <TD>
          ${Data.getValue1().get(i)}
     </tr>
</Table>
```

**Finally,** you need to call the code!  Until you learn more about JQuery, just put everything in a Document Ready block.  I will also insert a column with the "important column data" from above.  It should look like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#radioButton').click(function() {
        var tableText = '<table id="newTable">';
            tableText += '<tr>';
                tableText += '<td>';
                    tableText += $('#importantColumnData').html();
                tableText += '</td>';
            tableText += '</tr>';
        tableText += '</table>';
        $('#firstTable').after(tableText);
    });
});
```

Notice that we used the IDs in this JQuery code that we added to the HTML elements previously, using the '#' sign.  This symbol is used for IDs, and a period(.) is used for classes, just like in CSS.  While there is a way to break strings up over multiple lines to avoid this hassle, as a Javascript newbie I recommend getting used to basic syntax first to avoid human error.  If you've got any other questions let me know.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Lavalamp, its really a very helpful answer. so, once the radiobutton id is clicked the #newTable is getting created after the #firstTable. the columns inside the new table, can it be also dynamically populated from any datasource? also how can I have the column value GenID from #firstTable to show in my #newTable.

Comment: You can feed JQuery's .after() method any string, so I would populate a variable.  That way, you can concatenate strings together and then just put that variable between the parentheses in the .after() method.  Javascript's concatenation operator is the Plus Sign(+).  You can get a column's HTML using the .html() method.  Despite there being no problems with tables and Javascript/JQuery on paper, I have found in practice there often are and you should try and incorporate spans/divs into your tables if possible to avoid any problems.  I will update the answer with this updated information.

Comment: (If I was helpful, please be sure to upvote/accept my answer!  I'm on "probation" right now with Stack Overflow for asking apparently stupid questions related to Java and I can't ask any more questions until I help people.)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Lavalamp for the answer, just one more quick question, can I also generate a dynamic table having fixed columns but multiple rows.Basically, what i am trying to achieve here is, to get GenID value from #firstTable and click radioButton(which will further query from database using that GenID and populate the results in a #newTable after #firstTable). I hope I did not confused you.

Comment: Are you asking if you can have "template" values for different columns to insert at various spots in your dynamically created rows?  If so, sure, just put the "template" column string in its own variable so you can add it to your dynamic row wherever you need it.  If this is not what you meant, please explain further.

Comment: Sure, you could use an expression that finds a column in each table, and puts the inner HTML of one of those columns into the other: $('#employee').find('#id').html($('#employee_detail').find('#designation').html());

Comment: Like for example, There is an employee table with columns:- id,name, salary,address; once I have the id from employee table, i can access another table called "employee_detail" having columns:-designation,manager,team,department; So now, relating to my problem, my #firstTable is like "employee" table where i have GenID, which I need to access - #newTable like "employee_details" in above example, to get further details; and then populate it accordingly in a generated table. Please let me know If I am clear in explaining myself and the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally edited a previous comment, but I see you saw it because you marked it up.  Did that help?  If not, I'd appreciated it if you could give the potential HTML for these tables in an Edit to your original question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44932/discussion-between-akiiddweeber-and-mr-lavalamp)

Comment: Oh Let me repost it here: Thank you Mr.Lavalamp. the solution you gave it did help, but guess the problem now I am facing have different mode but on the same platform. That is, I made a JSP database connection which is generating a table based on the query I provided ( a query having a where clause variable which we got from your solution the #importantColumnData) I am now figuring it out how to put the correct syntax and add the jsp connection along with the JQuery script.

Comment: [contd]-which will finally generate me a #newTable with all the updated columns right after I click the radio button. So its like this #firstTable having radioButton-> clicked->#importandDataColumn retrieved and saved->used #importantDataColumn value in JSP database connection-> queried from database->show result in a dynamic table that is generated after clicking radion button

Answer (score 0):

```
var html;  
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);

            html = '<input type="radio" name="test" onclick= pop()>';
            cell1.innerHTML = html; 
            html = '${Data.getGenId().get(i)}';
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            cell2.innerHTML = html; 
           html ='${Data.getValue1().get(i)}>'</td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

call the function on onclick event of radio button

```
function myFunction()
{
    var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
    cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
}
```